# File suddenly not showing up in Intellij Idea "Go to file..."

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

So I was working on a project on IntelliJ Idea 2017.2.4 CE and suddenly one specific java file stopped appearing on the "go to file..." search bar. It shows up in "Search everything" but "Go to file" is what I normally use, and it seems kind of random that one specific file with nothing special about it suddenly stopped appearing on the search results. I don't know what could have caused the problem, does anyone know if there is an "excluded files" list for that particular search?

Comment: check the search file mask? Is it set on *.*?

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder that solved the problem! It was probably a random bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases this problem is caused by the corrupted caches.

`File` | `Invalidate Caches` | **Invalidate and Restart** should fix it.